# How to use xsl:use-attribute-sets properly?

Tags: xml, xslt, intellij-idea, xsl-fo

I am creating some PDF 's using XSL - FO.

This is my header in my .fo file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
```

Right after this I have:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="versionParam" select="'1.0'"/>

<xsl:attribute-set name="captionColumnSet">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">7pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Then when I try using my **attribute set** like this:

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="captionColumnSet">
    <fo:block>
        test
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Well the text will be 16pt. No problems here. However IntelliJ constantly complains saying:

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: IntelliJ complaning annoys me so much, I would switch to a different approach if it exists. My whole file seems red currently and I could not find a way to stop this check.

According to this it should be all fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256104.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77511), feel free to [vote](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23368682).

Comment: Thanks. Any way to switch it off?

Comment: You can try lowering the highlighting level for this file using the Hector icon in the status bar, but it will also disable other features.

Comment: possibly you should switch to an FO aware editor like oXygen.